# Use of "#each" with multiple variables in Handlebars

Tags: handlebars.js

How to "select" a value with "this" when there are multiple #each in Handelbars ?

```
                {{#each marqueauction}}
                {{#each modelauction}}
                <div class="results__container--box">
                    {{this.marqueauction}}
                    {{this.modelauction}}
                </div>
                {{else}}
                <div class="results__container--box">
                    <p>Aucun résultat d'enchères n'est disponible pour ce modèle.</p>
                </div>
                {{/each}}
                {{/each}}
```

EDIT: I want to call my MongoDB database with mongoose and display results in a box container. For that, I loop through my results array.

My Mongoose model:

```
const DemocarauctionSchema = new Schema({
    objectID: {
        type: Number
    },
    cars_getroute: {
        type: String
    },
    gm_url: {
        type: String
    },
    "results": { type: [{
        marque: {
            type: String
        },
        model: {
            type: String
        },
        model_year: {
            type: String
        },
        price_str: {
            type: String
        },
        prince_int: {
            type: Number
        },
        price_currency: {
            type: String
        },
        sold: {
            type: Boolean
        },
        auction_house: {
            type: String
        },
        auction_country: {
            type: String
        },
        auction_date: {
            type: String
        },
        auction_datetime: {
            type: String
        },
        auction_url: {
            type: String
        },
        image_urls: {
            type: String
        },
        price_int_eu: {
            type: Number
        },
    }]}    
}
```

I loop through the array in Express/Node:

```
const [democarauctions] = result;

        let marqueauction = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < democarauctions.results.length; i++) {
            marqueauction.push(democarauctions.results[i].marque)
        }

        let modelauction = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < democarauctions.results.length; i++) {
            modelauction.push(democarauctions.results[i].model)
        }
...
```

And I call the results array in my "res.render":

```
res.render(demo, {
            results: democarauctions.results,
            marqueauction: marqueauction,
            modelauction: modelauction,
            modelyearauction: modelyearauction,
            etc.})
```

Now I'd like to render on my HTML multiple box for each result, with marqueauction, modelauction, modelyearauction in each one. I use handlebars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is best to avoid `this` and instead use named [block parameters](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/block-helpers.html#block-parameters) :

```
{{#each marqueauction as |marque|}}
  {{#each modelauction as |model|}}
    <div class="results__container--box">
      {{marque}}
      {{model}}
    </div>
  {{else}}
    <div class="results__container--box">
      <p>Aucun résultat d'enchères n'est disponible pour ce modèle.</p>
    </div>
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

I'm not sure why you are breaking apart the original collection into multiple collections and then trying to combine them again in the presentation.  Just use the results directly.

EDIT: based on your updated question:

```
{{#each results as |auction|}}
  <div class="results__container--box">
    {{auction.marque}}
    {{auction.model}}
  </div>
{{else}}
  <div class="results__container--box">
    <p>Aucun résultat d'enchères n'est disponible pour ce modèle.</p>
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Thankyou, but my error is that modelauction is not nested in marqueauction and I don't know how to display them on the same level...

Comment: So you have two unrelated collections?   I don't understand "same level".  Can you edit your question and clarify?

Comment: No, it's the same collection but modelauction is not nested in marqueauction. So when I try with your example, it doesn't work (I think it's the problem).

It's simply: "marqueauction": "Ferrari"
                  "modelauction": "456"

And I can't display them in the container box

Comment: In your question (not in comments), supply examples of the two collections and an example of what you want to produce.  Otherwise, I can't really understand what you're trying to accomplish.